# Is it possible to create a named function from a closure?

Tags: php

In PHP, you can have named functions like this:

```
function foo()
{
   return "bar";
}
```

And you can have Closures like this:

```
$foo = function() {
    return "bar";
};
```

Closures are awesome and easy to create, but unfortunately a library I need to use really wants a named function. Is it possible to create a named function from closures dynamically? I.e. not defining all functions in code ahead of time, but more like a `register_function($name, callable $closure)`.

I am aware of `create_function`, but that one takes a PHP string as function body and just `eval`s it, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: what do you mean, "wants a named function"? you have to do `library_function('my_func')`, and then it does `function library_function($func) { $func(); }`?

Comment: @MarcB: I wish it did that. No, the library is Smarty and the use case is registering plugins. It does specific compilation of your template depending on what kind of callable you give it, and that currently does not support Closures. It is either instance methods, static methods, or named functions.

Comment: So smarty wants a named function but you don't want to name it?

Comment: I cannot them, as they really are runtime defined closures. Think of it as `foreach ($things as $thing) { $closure = getClosureForThing($thing); registerClosure($closure); }`. Anyway, the exact use is slightly too much for the scope of the question. I just want to know if it is possible. If not, I'll have to wait until the relevant issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think if it is possible to create named functions out of closures on the fly but using [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method of a class, you may find this workaround helpful:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        if (isset($this->{$name}))
            return call_user_func_array($this->{$name}, $args);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
// Declaring a closure then assign it to $bar property of Foo
$foo->bar = function () { 
    echo "bar"; 
};
// Call Foo method of the same name
$foo->bar();
```

Comment: It seems that is not possible indeed, and I ended up implementing something with with objects that simply call the appropriate closure. Your solution is nicer though, as it does not require instantiating an additional object per closure.

Answer (score 7):

You can create global array with callbacks. Add to this global array by `register_func($name, $callback)` and call function by `call_func($name, $parameter1, $parameter2, ...)`.

Without using `eval` I think this is not possible to create named function from callback.

Comment: Global variables as well as namespaces should be avoided as a general good practice. If you have to make a 'god' data object at least vendor namespace it.

Comment: @Pheagey it's simple idea. I know that better solution is - for example - singleton callbacks-container class. But I just want to show a draft - not a complete solution.

Comment: Ah, yes, very good then. Just did not want to give the OP to get in the habit of bad practices. Carry on :)

Comment: @Pheagey I don't understand - if you have a better solution go ahead! Write it! ;)

Answer (score 3):

My proposal is to use a static methods because they can be call like simple functions. We can achive this with magic function `__callStatic` like in this code

```
<?php

class FunctionsProvider
{
    protected static $closures = [];

    public static function addClosure($name, $closure)
    {
        if (is_callable($closure)) {
            static::$closures[$name] = $closure;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Closure is not callable');
        }
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, static::$closures)) {       
            return call_user_func_array(static::$closures[$name], $arguments);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Unknown method');
        }
    }
}

//Lets prepare sample closure
$foo = function() {
    return "bar";
};

FunctionsProvider::addClosure('foo', $foo);

$return = FunctionsProvider::foo();

var_dump($return);
```

On the output we will get

> string(3) "bar"

Answer (score 3):

I managed to create one using evil `eval`, [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and [SuperClosure](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) library.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

function register_function(string $name, Closure $closure)
{
    $serializedBody = (new SuperClosure\Serializer)->serialize($closure);

    $obj = unserialize($serializedBody);
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('data');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $data = $property->getValue($obj);
    $body = preg_replace('/^function \(/', "function {$name} (", $data['code']);

    eval($body);
}

$closure = function($a = 1, $b = 2, $c = 3) {
    var_dump(compact('a', 'b', 'c'));
};

register_function('test', $closure);

var_dump(function_exists('test')); // true

test(13, 2, 3);
// array(3) {
//   ["a"]=>
//   int(13)
//   ["b"]=>
//   int(2)
//   ["c"]=>
//   int(3)
// }
```

Comment: @Skysplit I hope you did this only to exercise your PHP knowledge and we will never see this in any real project.

Comment: @d3jn I definitely do not plan to use it in any project :) It was fun thing to check though (back then)!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot name a \Closure object in PHP.

While I am sure there is an API to do this, it is not exposed at the PHP level. One could possibly write a C Plugin to expose a User-land php function to name the function.